# Statistics - Real world - combining normal distributions

Tags: statistics, finance

I want to keep track of $12$ financial instruments each of which updates independently from the others. There is a calculation that I want to perform that involves all $12$ numbers so every time an instrument updates I will need to recalculate my metric.

With no real good reason, I am going to assume that the logarithm of the time between updates will approximate a normal distribution - *Is there a better assumption I could make prior to gathering any data?*

Then given $12$ normal distributions, how can I calculate how frequently I need to recalculate my metric for it to stay up to date?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simpler assumption may be that the time between updates of each individual instrument has an [exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution), i.e. is a [Poisson process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process).

If the twelve updating processes are independent, then the time between updates of any of them would also be exponentially distributed, and happen at a *rate* (the reciprocal of the expected time) which is the sum of the rates of the individual processes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you elaborate slightly with a small example? Maybe 3 instruments?

Comment: My understanding is that with 3 exponential distributions $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3$ we can create a new exponential distribution $\lambda = \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \lambda_3$. Is it that simple?

Comment: @BenCrossley - Yes (assuming independence) it is that simple for Poisson processes, and equivalently for the minimum of independent exponentially distributed random variables